# Compiling GMP Library with Mingw on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, mingw, gmp

I try to compile my written C++ code G++ [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) on Windows. My program works fine on Ubuntu. I need to recompile and build the library with Mingw-G++ to eventually compile my final program with Mingw for Windows.

#### My problem now:

The configure file provided with the library does not look like it can set Mingw-GCC over GCC as compiler anywhere. You can set flags for build and host type but they don't bring the desired results (in my testing).
Im far from being an expert with makefiles and shell scripts, so it might *seem* like I can't set the compiler, but I think I just overlook something. I can imagine that i need so set the path to Mingw in the configure file myself, but i dont want to break anything **YET**.

I figured out that there is a CClist in the `configure` file, which is set to `gcc` / `gcc icc` etc... it determines which list of compilers to set depending on the CPU build type (arm/amd64/etc...).<

Another problem: the mingw gcc compiler on linux isn't named gcc unlike on windows but rather `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`...so the script can't detect it as gcc

Thanks in advance

#### Edit

After some help from @SuperStormer i set the compiler as `mingw32-gcc` correctly as my `config.status` file show, however make check fails with the following warnings:

```
z.lo spinner.lo trace.lo  ../libgmp.la 
libtool: warning: '-no-install' is ignored for x86_64-w64-mingw32
libtool: warning: assuming '-no-fast-install' instead
libtool: link: x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar cq .libs/libtests.a  memory.o misc.o refmpf.o refmpn.o refmpq.o refmpz.o spinner.o trace.o
libtool: link: x86_64-w64-mingw32-ranlib .libs/libtests.a
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libtests.la" && ln -s "../libtests.la" "libtests.la" )
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I..   -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -c -o t-bswap.o t-bswap.c
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc  -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -no-install  -o t-bswap.exe t-bswap.o libtests.la ../libgmp.la 
libtool: warning: '-no-install' is ignored for x86_64-w64-mingw32
libtool: warning: assuming '-no-fast-install' instead
libtool: link: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -o t-bswap.exe t-bswap.o  ./.libs/libtests.a /home/me/Downloads/gmp-6.2.1/.libs/libgmp.a ../.libs/libgmp.a
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I..   -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -c -o t-constants.o t-constants.c
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc  -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -no-install  -o t-constants.exe t-constants.o libtests.la ../libgmp.la 
libtool: warning: '-no-install' is ignored for x86_64-w64-mingw32
libtool: warning: assuming '-no-fast-install' instead
libtool: link: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -o t-constants.exe t-constants.o  ./.libs/libtests.a /home/me/Downloads/gmp-6.2.1/.libs/libgmp.a ../.libs/libgmp.a
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I..   -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -c -o t-count_zeros.o t-count_zeros.c
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc  -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -no-install  -o t-count_zeros.exe t-count_zeros.o libtests.la ../libgmp.la 
libtool: warning: '-no-install' is ignored for x86_64-w64-mingw32
libtool: warning: assuming '-no-fast-install' instead
libtool: link: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -o t-count_zeros.exe t-count_zeros.o  ./.libs/libtests.a /home/me/Downloads/gmp-6.2.1/.libs/libgmp.a ../.libs/libgmp.a
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I..   -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -c -o t-hightomask.o t-hightomask.c
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc  -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -no-install  -o t-hightomask.exe t-hightomask.o libtests.la ../libgmp.la 
libtool: warning: '-no-install' is ignored for x86_64-w64-mingw32
libtool: warning: assuming '-no-fast-install' instead
libtool: link: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -o t-hightomask.exe t-hightomask.o  ./.libs/libtests.a /home/me/Downloads/gmp-6.2.1/.libs/libgmp.a ../.libs/libgmp.a
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I..   -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -c -o t-modlinv.o t-modlinv.c
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc  -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -no-install  -o t-modlinv.exe t-modlinv.o libtests.la ../libgmp.la 
libtool: warning: '-no-install' is ignored for x86_64-w64-mingw32
libtool: warning: assuming '-no-fast-install' instead
libtool: link: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -o t-modlinv.exe t-modlinv.o  ./.libs/libtests.a /home/me/Downloads/gmp-6.2.1/.libs/libgmp.a ../.libs/libgmp.a
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I..   -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -c -o t-popc.o t-popc.c
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc  -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -no-install  -o t-popc.exe t-popc.o libtests.la ../libgmp.la 
libtool: warning: '-no-install' is ignored for x86_64-w64-mingw32
libtool: warning: assuming '-no-fast-install' instead
libtool: link: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -o t-popc.exe t-popc.o  ./.libs/libtests.a /home/me/Downloads/gmp-6.2.1/.libs/libgmp.a ../.libs/libgmp.a
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I..   -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -c -o t-parity.o t-parity.c
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc  -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -no-install  -o t-parity.exe t-parity.o libtests.la ../libgmp.la 
libtool: warning: '-no-install' is ignored for x86_64-w64-mingw32
libtool: warning: assuming '-no-fast-install' instead
libtool: link: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -o t-parity.exe t-parity.o  ./.libs/libtests.a /home/me/Downloads/gmp-6.2.1/.libs/libgmp.a ../.libs/libgmp.a
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I..   -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -c -o t-sub.o t-sub.c
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc  -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -no-install  -o t-sub.exe t-sub.o libtests.la ../libgmp.la 
libtool: warning: '-no-install' is ignored for x86_64-w64-mingw32
libtool: warning: assuming '-no-fast-install' instead
libtool: link: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 -mtune=k8 -march=k8 -o t-sub.exe t-sub.o  ./.libs/libtests.a /home/me/Downloads/gmp-6.2.1/.libs/libgmp.a ../.libs/libgmp.a
make[4]: Verzeichnis „/home/me/Downloads/gmp-6.2.1/tests“ wird verlassen
```

and this

```
FAIL: t-bswap.exe
FAIL: t-constants.exe
FAIL: t-count_zeros.exe
FAIL: t-hightomask.exe
FAIL: t-modlinv.exe
FAIL: t-popc.exe
FAIL: t-parity.exe
FAIL: t-sub.exe
============================================================================
Testsuite summary for GNU MP 6.2.1
============================================================================
# TOTAL: 8
# PASS:  0
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  8
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0
============================================================================
See tests/test-suite.log
```

Test-suite-log says: it can't run the .exe file. It's clear to me why it can't, but is there any workaround to create a linux excutable instead? Or is make check expected to fail?

#### Solution

Quick guess is that make check can't succeed on linux with mingw.
I ran make install, and my program now runs fine (regarding my library issues)

Comment: Repo for potential answerers: https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/. What commands are you running to build the library?

Comment: Shouldn't setting the CC or CXX environment variable to your mingw gcc work?

Comment: @SuperStormer currently i just build the lib with ```./configure --enable-cxx```,```make```, ```make check && make install```

Comment: I don't have any global env variables for gcc or any compiler as far as i know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is mostly based on this [mailing list post](https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-bugs/2020-January/004714.html).

Commands ran:

```
export CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
export CC_FOR_BUILD=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
./configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-cxx
make
```

Tweak this however you want.

Comment: I highly appreciate your help. The configuration works fine, however make check fails. I will add the error log to my question

Comment: I read the post aswell i try to figure it out myself, but any help is welcome

Comment: Yeah, make check is supposed to fail if your environment doesn't support running windows executables(it works on mine, because of WSL).